# jQuery Image Roll-over fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

This has probably been asked a lot, and I see a whole bunch of different solutions, some of which I cant get to work myself.

My goal is to build a menu, however to start out, it would be a good idea to get a single button working first, yeah?

So I tried to follow the [Dragon Interactive](http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/pufferfish_article.php) tutorial

Heres my code:

CSS:

```
#navigation a { 
    position: relative; 
    }

#navigation a .hover {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hover").css({'opacity':'0'});
$('#navigation li a').hover(function() {

    // Stuff that happens when you hover on
    $('.hover').animate({
        'opacity': 1
        }, 700)

},function() {

    // Stuff that happens when you unhover
    $('.hover').animate({
        'opacity': 0
        }, 700)

});
});


</script>
```

And of course the HTML markup.

```
<p>
Just some random giberish here, to make sure the positioning
<br>
works regardless of what junk I have before and after it. :)
</p>

<ul id="navigation" style="list-style-type: none; list-style-position:outside;">
<li>
<a href="http://google.com"><img id="btn1" border="none" src="https://dom28edjsbv6i.cloudfront.net/Images/GetPlan.png" />
</a><span class="hover"><img src="https://dom28edjsbv6i.cloudfront.net/Images/GetPlan_MO.png" /></span>
</li>

</ul>
```

I've tried changing different parameters, and I am completely lost.

Should I use a div, and animate the background image? Would that produce the same "img" link effect, or is that just bad coding?

Basically, what I am asking, is a minimal solution that is replicateable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this effect, for example a [pure CSS3 approach](http://dinolatoga.com/demo/webkit-image-hover-effects/) or the JavaScript approach you have taken. If you have specific browser requirements then the JavaScript approach is probably the best option.

The problem in your existing code is that the animation events will fire continually whilst the cursor is `hovering`. You should look into the [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) jQuery events and also stop() so that quickly entering and leaving the `<a>` does not queue up lots of fade in/out animations.

The other problem you have is that the non-hovered `<img>` and hovered `<img>` are next to each other. It is a better approach to keep the HTML simple and usable without the JavaScript hovering effect. Therefore use one `<img>` tag with the the non-hovered `src` and manipulate the `src` and opacity in JavaScript to create the hover effect.

**Edit:** Here is just [***one* way**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHVBp/) of doing it. It works by [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)ing the `<img>` first, which due to the combination of `position:relative` on the parent `<a>` and `position:absolute` on the `<img>` places the clone directly over the top of the original. The opacity of the clone is then animated. It relies on your *hovered* images always ending with `_MO`. This is an unobtrusive way of doing this, since a user without JavaScript (they still exist!) will have clean single image HTML.

An alternate approach could be to use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) but you will still have solve the fading.

There are plenty of browsers that would support the CSS3 approach, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE9. In my experience, your target audience often dictates what approach is taken when it comes to this sort of development.

**Edit 2:** Code clarification…

```
$('#navigation li a img').each(function(index) {
    $(this).clone().css({'opacity':0}).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.png','_MO.png')).appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

… takes each `<img>` descendent of an `<a>`, first cloning that `<img>` element, then sets the opacity to 0 (hidden), then changes the `src` attribute of the clone to the *hovered* version of the image and then adding the cloned DOM element as a child of the `<img>`s parent node in the DOM, which is the `<a>`. It takes advantage of [jQuery chaining](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip10), but could be written explicitly as:

```
$('#navigation li a img').each(function(index) {
    var clonedImgElement = $(this).clone();
    var parentAnchorElement = $(this).parent();
    var originalSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var hoveredSrc = originalSrc.replace('.png','_MO.png');
    clonedImgElement.css({'opacity':0}); // hide clone first
    clonedImgElement.attr('src', hoveredSrc); // update the src to the hovered version
    clonedImgElement.appendTo(parentAnchorElement); // attach clone to anchor in DOM
});
```

**Edit 3:**

You could also replace the hover code with:

```
$('#navigation li a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('img').filter(':last').stop().animate({'opacity':1});

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('img').filter(':last').stop().animate({'opacity':0});
});
```

which according to [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) offers better performance.

**Edit 4** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHVBp/5/) to work with images in other containers, now only position the clones rather than *all* images so that the non-hovered images still exist in normal page flow and also works with images not at `top:0;left:0`

Comment: I thought the hover was Hover(in,out) ? I am looking for a JS approach, not many browser support CSS3 AFAIK :)

Comment: How can I animate the SRC change? That would be the best solution!

Comment: I've added a demo of one way to do this, cloning the `<img>` and animating the opacity of the clone.

Comment: Nice one - however I am not sure I understand, the first long line is a bit confusing - would you mind breaking it down? Using code is one thing, but we dont learn if we dont know whats going on behind the scenes. :)

Comment: Of course (and a +1 for your comment). I have added a breakdown of the chained functions that I hope helps clarify my answer

Comment: Okay, so you are cloning the element, and on the MouseEnter event, you find it by img:last, because it was the last image to be added to the DOM, correct? How would I do this for a menu, where there are multiple hover images? :)

Comment: The [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) jQuery extension selects the last matched element within the selector, so it is actually just finding the last (or second) `<img>` descendant of any given `<a>`, so it would work with multiple `<a>` elements, each with a normal and a hovered `<img>`. I have updated answer with more performant `:last` selector code based on the jQuery documentation linked above.

Comment: Would it be possible to make your solution a reusable function? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The code should work as-is with any number of menu items as the jQuery selector operates on all matched `img` elements.

Comment: I mean, like `InitImgHover(ImgParent,ImgSrc,ImgSrcHover)`? :) I will probably figure it out

Comment: @Jeff let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1369/discussion-between-andyb-and-jeff)

Answer (score 1):

You call the same event on both functions. Each is a hover event. Maybe you should try different events like mouseover and mouseout oder something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were on the right track, but missed a couple of things:

`hover` span should be inside the `a`nchor tag:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
   <img id="btn1" border="none" 
       src="https://dom28edjsbv6i.cloudfront.net/Images/GetPlan.png" />
   <span class="hover">
       <img src="https://dom28edjsbv6i.cloudfront.net/Images/GetPlan_MO.png" /> 
   </span>
</a>
```

`hover` span should be positioned right on top of the initial image:

```
    #navigation a .hover {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -45px;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }
```

here's your tweaked solution: http://jsfiddle.net/W8KMe/3/